# Calling a WebService of a ASP.NET MVC 4 from Java client

Tags: c#, java, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC 4 (in C#) web application. 
This application involves interaction with a local Java application.

I want to upload a file from Java to the ASP.NET server and store it in a database.
My question is: How do I expose a ASP.NET MVC method so that it may be called by Java.
Does it need to be a Web Service? How do I insert a Web Service in a ASP.NET MVC application?
My idea it was to expose a controller method of ASP.NET MVC that may be receive a file from Java.

I just don't know if such a thing is possible, and how do I call a controller function from a Java app and that controller may receive a file.

Best Regards,
William.

Comment: What you want is a WebAPI controller.

Comment: Use ASP.NET WebApi http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis

Comment: Thank you. To store a file in a DB, what's the most appropriated object? The HttpPostedFileBase one?